# How do I calculate a Sum based on multiple If's in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, sum

Background is that I'm making a budget spreadsheet. I have different bills due on different days. (ie. bill due on Monday and bill due on the 10th)

I want a function that will place the appropriate amount of money going in/out in column D and the description of why the money is going in/out in column E.

Currently I have two different formulas that I created (probably incorrectly).

Formula for Column E:  (Already is in the document and seems to work fine other than that fact that I cant add additional text to the cell)

```
=IF(DAY(C36)=7," Amy Pay","")&IF(DAY(C36)=22," Amy Pay","")&IF(DAY(C36)=8," Family Bills","")&IF(DAY(C36)=6," Dollar Shave Club","")&IF(DAY(C36)=2," Amy Cap One VISA","")&IF(DAY(C36)=3," Chase VISA","")&IF(DAY(C36)=8," Being Smart","")&IF(DAY(C36)=17," Gym","")&IF(DAY(C36)=11," Netflix","")&IF(DAY(C36)=19," Cap One MC","")&IF(DAY(C36)=29," CenturyLink","")&IF(DAY(C36)=6," Haley Cap One Visa","")&IF(DAY(C36)=10," SRP","")&IF(DAY(C36)=23, "Car Payment","")&IF(DAY(C36)=30, "Rent","")&IF((B36)="Mon"," Monday","")&IF((B36)="Fri"," Friday","")&IF((B36)="Fri"," Haley Pay","")
```

Formula for Column D:  (not in the column yet, as it doesn't work how I want)

```
=IF(DAY(B40)=7,"1474.22","")&IF(DAY(B40)=22,"1474.22","")&IF(DAY(B40)=8,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=6,"-9","")&IF(DAY(B40)=2,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=3,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=8,"-400","")&IF(DAY(B40)=17,"-20.05","")&IF(DAY(B40)=11,"-8.63","")&IF(DAY(B40)=19,"-450","")&IF(DAY(B40)=29,"-50","")&IF(DAY(B40)=6,"-150","")&IF(DAY(B40)=10,"-200","")&IF(DAY(B40)=23,"-325","")&IF(DAY(B40)=30,"-500","")&IF((A40)="Mon","-125","")&IF((A40)="Fri","-325","")&IF((A40)="Fri","400","")
```

[http://imgur.com/IBINweh](https://imgur.com/IBINweh)

[image]

The problem is that in column D, rather than providing a sum of the numbers, it lists the numbers in the column.

[http://imgur.com/rPDS5h2](https://imgur.com/rPDS5h2)

[image]

I had a suggestion to add =SUM( in front of the IF(  function, but when I do, #VALUE! is what results in the field. Using this formula:  (view image by changing appended text to /CVs0f1v )

```
=SUM(IF(DAY(B40)=7,"1474.22","")&IF(DAY(B40)=22,"1474.22","")&IF(DAY(B40)=8,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=6,"-9","")&IF(DAY(B40)=2,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=3,"-100","")&IF(DAY(B40)=8,"-400","")&IF(DAY(B40)=17,"-20.05","")&IF(DAY(B40)=11,"-8.63","")&IF(DAY(B40)=19,"-450","")&IF(DAY(B40)=29,"-50","")&IF(DAY(B40)=6,"-150","")&IF(DAY(B40)=10,"-200","")&IF(DAY(B40)=23,"-325","")&IF(DAY(B40)=30,"-500","")&IF((A40)="Mon","-125","")&IF((A40)="Fri","-325","")&IF((A40)="Fri","400",""))
```

Any ideas on how I can get all the to populate and sum appropriately?

Forgive my Non Excel Guru knowledge - trying to learn. :D

-Amy

Comment: Have you looked at the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and/or the [CONCATENATE function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/concatenate-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d)?

Comment: I could be wrong, but from what I understand the SUMIFS function is used to return one number based on multiple criteria, rather than to return multiple numbers based on multiple criteria.

Comment: I understood that the next stage in this problem was to retrieve sums based upon those descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

If you take all of the options from your first working formula and change the method retrieving them, you will have a much more versatile worksheet that can easily accept new additions and schedule modifications.

[image: Family Bill Payment Schedule]

1. In a couple of unused columns to the right, pit in the day-of-month and the action that occurs. I'm using columns Y & Z. You have two events occurring on the 6th so I put them together.
2. In a couple of other unused columns use the day-of-the-week and associated text.; I've used columns V & W. The default for Sunday is 1.
3. In E36 use this formula,
         `=TRIM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DAY(C36),$Y:$Z, 2, FALSE), "")&" "&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(C36),$V:$W, 2, FALSE), ""))`
4. Fill down as necessary.

If you want the day-of-the-week in column B, use `=C36` and use a custom number format of `ddd` or `dddd`.

References:

[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)
  [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940)

Comment: So, then to populate the dollar values associated with each bill, I would just add the dollar value next to the bill description?

Comment: Yes, but that would only work for one month unless the amounts (like rent) were static from month to month. The day-of-month reference would have to change from Y:Z to Y:AA (to allow for the extra column). To get the descriptons it would still be `..., 2, FALSE)` but to get the amounts it would be `..., 3, FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating text strings that look like numbers.  You probably want to be adding real numbers:

```
=SUM(IF(DAY(B40)=7,1474.22,0) + IF(DAY(B40)=22,0) + ...
```

although, whenever I see a formula as complex as what you have, I would consider looking for a different solution -- Vlookup comes to mind.

In addition, with a VLOOKUP table, you would have seen that you have some conflicts -- e.g: you list the same condition of B40=8 to return two different values; and the same condition of A40 = Fri, to also return two different values.